# Designing an email A/B Test / Split Test

Tags: ab-testing, abtest

I have 10,000 expired client email addresses. I want to send them an email with a discount to rejoin their membership.

I would like to A/B test to increase the conversion rate.

I have found tools that calculate statistical significance, eg
https://vwo.com/ab-split-test-significance-calculator/

This has number of emails as a variable.

How do I know how many emails to send in each test when I setup the test in advance?

There's a limit to how many tests I can run (10,000 max) - so i can't just let all tests run for ages - when it's done it's largely done. I need to maximise conversions.

Lets say we do 10 tests of 100 users each (as a split test that's 2,000 users).

If I run one A/B test and one converts more but it's not statistically significant - can I just take the bigger converting item, assume it's at least as good and move on?

I have read - don't remember where - that you should set test duration before each test. So if I fix at 100 emails - and it's not statistically significant - do I just ignore it? What is the harm choosing the better converting item? (presumably if after 100 items it's not statistically significant it's not that big a deal anyway)?

Thx

Answer (score 2):

The thing to understand about significnce is that it’s a function of both the size of the sample, as well as of the difference. The greater the difference, the less likely it is caused by mere chance. I am not familiar with a qualitative approach other than to play with significance (alpha) and strength (beta) and see what probabilities are supported by your dataset. Ultimately, it’s your decision whether to call a test at 70% alpha.  (Probably OK for emial.)

Comment: Thanks. So how do I go about beginning - just pull a figure out of my ass for how many emails to send for the test - eg 300? See if that gets statistical significance? I keep reading you should never call a test early too.

Answer (score 1):

[Ran into size limitation on the comment]

300 sounds like a reasonable number to start with.  Look [here](http://getvariant.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/PetClinicChart-1024x754.png): this simulates an experiment with a control (black) and two variants (red and green) I ran this simmulation for 95% significance and 90% strength. The solid lines are the cumulative rate of the test statistic (rate of conversion to the next page in this case), dense dashed lines are the sample sizes, and the sparce dashed lines are the size of the sample that would make the difference observed so far significant, over time. As you see, in the beginning the difference between control and a variant measures varies due to the small sample size, and, accordinly, varies the significant sample size. However, as the measures begin to stabilize, so do the significan sample sizes.  At some point, the significant sample sizes cross actual ones and stay under.  That’s the points of where you can safely call the tests for the chosen levels of significance and strength.  The red variant shows greater degradation wrt the control (from 0.1 to ~0.06, i.e. ~40% drop) and consequently its sample size reaches significance at just under 250 trials (the red dot at the intersection of the dotted red lines) . The green variant shows half that much of a drop and requires a much larger sample size of ~1100 (the green dot at the intersection of the dotted green lines). Hope this helps!

Comment: So you advocate stopping the test once statistical significance is reached? Apparently we shouldn't do this: http://data.heapanalytics.com/dont-stop-your-ab-tests-part-way-through/

Comment: Another piece saying don't call it early: http://conversionxl.com/12-ab-split-testing-mistakes-i-see-businesses-make-all-the-time/

Comment: As you can see from the graphs, statistical significance may be “reached” more than once.  Particularly early in the life of an experiment when measure volatility is still high, it’s easy to run into a false “significance” moment.  But at some point you need to call the test, right?!

Comment: What I took away from those articles was set a fixed length test for the start and always let it complete. I may have got it wrong though

Comment: Are you suggesting that I plot them on a graph usually? Are there rules of thumb / easy ways to know when you have "really" reached significance? Thx.

Comment: Yeah, I suggest my clients to plot and only settle when the test statistic (metric) has sufficiently stabilized.

Comment: how can I easily define 'stabilised'?